# XmlnsDefinitionAttribute and ambiguous types

Tags: xaml

Let's assume I have the following attributes on my assembly:

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("urn:foo", "NS1")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("urn:foo", "NS2")]
```

Then let's assume I have a few classes in that assembly:

```
namespace NS1
{
    public class Class1 {}
}

namespace NS1
{
    public class Class2 {}
}

namespace NS2
{
    // Here's the duplicate class name.  OK in C#, but ambiguous in XAML
    public class Class1 {}
}
```

Then let's assume that my XAML is like so:

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:foo="urn:foo"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <ListBox>
        <foo:Class2 />
        <foo:Class1 /> <!-- XAML parser does not like this: Ambiguous type reference -->
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

Putting aside any design issues with having two or more classes named the same within an assembly, is there any way to provide the needed specificity without resorting to this?

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:foo="urn:foo"
        xmlns:foo2="clr-namespace:NS2;assembly=AssemblyName"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <ListBox>
        <foo:Class2 />
        <foo2:Class1 />
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

In some special XAML syntax?  In an attribute I can put on `NS2.Class1` (e.g. `XamlClassName("NS2_Class1")`)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("urn:foo", "NS1")] 
[assembly: XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("urn:foo", "NS2")] 
[assembly: XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("urn:foo2", "NS2")]
```

and then:

```
xmlns:foo2="urn:foo2"
```

and finally:

```
<foo2:Class1 />
```

Regards,

H.Dolder

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I specifically want to avoid this (see above).

Comment: To avoid repeating this (in many of your XAML Files):
xmlns:foo2="clr-namespace:NS2;assembly=AssemblyName" 
I proposed this (in the Assembly):
[assembly: XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("urn:foo2", "NS2")] 
Regards,
H.Dolder